# MarketingCloud Analytics Builder Customization

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-reports

Are all the reports in the MC Analytics Builder Catalog static?  Or is there a level of customization available for these reports.

From what I can see - the answer is no, but I wanted to check with the experts.

My desire is the ability to do daily reporting at a higher level for my marketing director.  The catalog's *Email Send Summary* is a bit too in-depth for the quick status update.

Comment: i believe you could use the account send summary, but, do you need to produce certain metrics or ?

Comment: Yea, I was looking to overhaul the actual summary.  Really a customized report containing ONLY Subject line, send volume, bounce rate, click-through rate and a couple others.

Comment: Would a data export based on a DE work for your use case?